# Get an array of elements with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to capture a list of element: "TEXT TO CAPTURE 1", "TEXT TO  CAPTURE 2", ... scraping a web page with selenium and python.
The HTML of the page is the following:

```
<div class="contenedor" style="overflow:auto; padding: 6px;">
    <div style="width: 75px;">
        <p class="line1">
            <a href="http://www.somelink1.com/"><img src="https://www.somelink2.com" class="yborder" alt="Name"></a>
        </p>
        <p class="line1" style="align: center;">              
            <a href="www.somelink3.com" class="gensmall">TEXT TO CAPTURE 1</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 75px;">
        <p class="line1">
            <a href="www.somelink4.com"><img src="hwww.somelink5.com" class="yborder" alt="Dana Vespoli"></a>
        </p>
        <p class="line1" style="align: center;">              
            <a href="www.somelink6.com" class="gensmall">TEXT TO CAPTURE 2</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    ... others numbers of same <div> fields    ....

</div>
```

The number of element are change day by day I open the page so the number of the elements are undefined.

I can get only the first element with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'line1')]/following::a")
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `find_element_by_xpath` method, go for the `find_elements` method which will give you multiple elements.

Also, instead of Xpath, you can use the `class="gensmall">` to get the text (if this class is present in all the `a` tag.

Check this out

```
list_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a. gensmall')
for i in len(list_of_elements):
    print (i.text)
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: `find_elements_by_class_name('gensmall')`

Answer (score 1):

To extract the texts e.g. **TEXT TO CAPTURE 1**, **TEXT TO CAPTURE 2**, etc you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.contenedor p.line1>a.gensmall")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='contenedor']//p[@class='line1']/a[@class='gensmall']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```